# Why isn't this 3 dimensional array working?

Tags: javascript, arrays

### Code Summary

The code below is for a grid-based game I am designing - for learning purposes more than anything. The Game is played on an 8 x 8 grid. The player will be moving from one cell to another. There may or may not be a wall preventing their move.

#### Game Variables

**The Player Object**
Holds current position in game.

```
var player = {
    location: {
        x: 3,
        y: 3
    }
}
```

**The Grid**

```
board[x][y]   // An individual cell in the game
```

**Directions**

```
const NORTH = 0;
const EAST = 1;
const SOUTH = 2;
const WEST = 3;
```

**Walls**

```
board[x][y][NORTH] = 1;   // A wall on north wall
```

### Initial Testing

Testing was going fine when I was just testing if the player was moving off the board, as seen in the SWITCH statement below. But when I started checking to see if there was a WALL there, that's when things **blew up**.

I am starting my tests by resetting the game board, and remove all walls. This is what is breaking, I believe. I am getting this error:

[image: Error]

[image: Error Msg]

**Code**

```
const NORTH = 0;
const EAST = 1;
const SOUTH = 2;
const WEST = 3;

const ROOMWIDTH = 7; // 0 array
const ROOMHEIGHT = 7;

var moveResonse = {
    valid: 0,
    reason: "",
    helpText: ""
}

var player = {
    location: {
        x: 3,
        y: 3
    }

}

var board = [];

for(var x=0; x<8; x++){
    for(y=0; y<8; y++){
       for(var d=0; d<4;d++){
           board[x][y][d] = 0;
       }  
    }
}


// Testing. Put a WALL on WEST wall of 3,3
board[3][3][0] = 0;
board[3][3][1] = 0;
board[3][3][2] = 0;
board[3][3][3] = 1;

// Same WALL on EAST 2,3
board[2][3][0] = 0;
board[2][3][1] = 1;
board[2][3][2] = 0;
board[2][3][3] = 0;


function move(d) {
    // 1.  Is user trying to move off board?
    switch (d) {
        case NORTH:
            if (player.location.y - 1 < 0) {
                moveResonse = {
                    valid: 0,
                    reason: "Out of bounds",
                    helpText: "You can't move NORTH off the grid!"
                }
            }
            return moveResonse;
            break;

        case EAST:
            if (player.location.x + 1 > ROOMWIDTH) {
                moveResonse = {
                    valid: 0,
                    reason: "Out of bounds",
                    helpText: "You can't move EAST off the grid!"
                }
            }
            return moveResonse;
            break;

        case SOUTH:
            if (player.location.y + 1 > ROOMHEIGHT) {
                moveResonse = {
                    valid: 0,
                    reason: "Out of bounds",
                    helpText: "You can't move SOUTH off the grid!"
                }
            }
            return moveResonse;
            break;

        case WEST:
            if (player.location.x - 1 < 0) {
                moveResonse = {
                    valid: 0,
                    reason: "Out of bounds",
                    helpText: "You can't move WEST off the grid!"
                }
            }
            return moveResonse;
            break;
    }

    //2. Is there a wall there?
    if(board[player.location.x][player.location.y][d] == 1){
        moveResonse = {
            valid: 0,
            reason: "Obstacle",
            helpText: "You can't move there, a WALL there!"
        }
        return moveResonse;  
    }

}

//alert(`Moving North: ${move(NORTH).helpText}`);
//alert(`Moving SOUTH: ${move(SOUTH).helpText}`);
//alert(`Moving EAST: ${move(EAST).helpText}`);
alert(`Moving WEST: ${move(WEST).helpText}`);
```

Recently I had a question closed because some thought it was opinion based. I am not asking for 'opinions' , I am asking for help in finding a solution to the problem. If that means taking a different direction, well so be it. I greatly appreciate you helping me learn.

#### Visual of Board

[image: Board]

Comment: I just noticed a typo, moveResonse.  I use intellisense that's why I didn't catch it until now. That has nothing to do with my error, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only declared 1 dimension array doing var board = [];

```
for(var x=0; x<8; x++){
    board[x] = [];          // Added this line to create an empty array
    for(var y=0; y<8; y++){ 
       board[x][y] = [];    // Added this line to create an empty array
       for(var d=0; d<4;d++){
           board[x][y][d] = 0;
       }  
    }
}
```

You also missed out var in the 2nd for next loop. It becomes a global variable if you do not include it.

Comment: Thanks to all. For some reason, I assumed once I declared an array, I could add more arrays without declaring them. Now I know better. Working fine now, I do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Error]

My interpretation of this error message is that you haven't fully defined `board` as a three-dimensional array.

Looking at your code proves this out.

```
var board = [];

for(var x=0; x<8; x++){
    for(y=0; y<8; y++){
       for(var d=0; d<4;d++){
           board[x][y][d] = 0;
       }  
    }
}
```

You're defining `board` as a normal array, not even a 2-d array (let alone 3-d).
The error is appearing because it is interpreting the line `board[x][y][d]` from left to right. First, it evaluates `board[0]` (since `x` starts at 0); since you've defined `board` as an empty array, this will return `null`. Then, you're calling `[0]` on it (since `y` starts at 0; however, since the previous result was `null`, you're calling `null[0]`, which errors out.

To fix this, just make sure that you're actually creating the 3-d array, either in advance (when you define `board`) or as you go through each level of the for loop.